# PrestaShop Payment Module categorized as "other"

Tags: php, e-commerce, prestashop

I developed a prestashop module that integrates with an external/3rd-party payment gateway. It works but an issue still persist, my module always listed in the "other" category", unlike supposed to be categorized as "payments and gateways" module.

the skeleton class extneds PaymentModule  class and the "tab" filed set to be "payments_gateways" as tutored in your documentation.

How can I list my module in the  payments modules list, as results, my customer can recognize it and configure it easily

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have top set the module's category in the config.xml file in the root of your module:

```
<tab><![CDATA[payments_gateways]]></tab>
```